# MVC 5, want to add email address to userprofile, which table should I add to? userprofile or webpages_membership? (database design)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-design

I have a new MVC5 web app, and currently, as of default, 
table: userprofile
stores username and userId.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserProfile] (
[UserId]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[UserName]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[FirstName]         VARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
[LastName]          VARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);
```

table: webpages_membership stores userpassword.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[webpages_Membership] (
[UserId]                                  INT            NOT NULL,
[CreateDate]                              DATETIME       NULL,
[ConfirmationToken]                       NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
[IsConfirmed]                             BIT            DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
[LastPasswordFailureDate]                 DATETIME       NULL,
[PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess]        INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[Password]                                NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[PasswordChangedDate]                     DATETIME       NULL,
[PasswordSalt]                            NVARCHAR (128) NOT NULL,
[PasswordVerificationToken]               NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
[PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate] DATETIME       NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
);
```

I want to add emailaddress and emailaddressConfirmed to the table. which one should I add to? Or build one bit table that encompasses everything?

Also, I know nothing about membership and roles, should I invest sometime to learn about it? (Or is it only useful for esoteric things? )

Comment: Tag with appropriate DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends heavily on a use-case basis, but in general it would considered better to add it to the UserProfile table.

If you would like the user to CRUD on his/her e-mail address, then storing the e-mail field in the UserProfile table is best for various reasons.

- Minimizing database calls. Storing all the properties of User upon which he has (potentially various levels of) CRUD access in a single table allows you to access your database once when Fetching/Updating data for that particular user.
- Model elegance. A slight tangent on the above, accessing one table for all the properties you will add to your model (and/or viewmodel) passed to your View, your code (C# or SQL in a sproc, depending on where you put the logic) will be more elegant and easier to read, avoids JOINs etc.

Plenty of other reasons, many of which I do not understand fully, but those two are foremost, minimizing calls and code cleanlyness. There are also reasons against it:

- Protected Information. Do you consider e-mail sensitive information in your setting? Are there laws surrounding this information in your domain (E.G.: Some US Schools e-mail is protected via FERPA)? Protected information may require permission changes, and storing them in an unsecure fashion or displaying them in an untimely manner can put you in legal scope.

Again various use cases and your specific project may call for different design, a smaller standalone project may require one design, whereas a huge enterprise project may require a more streamlined design and potential worries about falling into some legal scope.

As for memberships/roles, they are certainly useful in an enterprise level database settings, where permissions may become necessary, but the 'should you invest time' is too subjective to really answer.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I am building a small application, so probably will add it in the userprofile table. 

It does save a a lot of time and effort to have to access database only once.